# Sickness note from doctor after i already got my monthly salary

Tags: sickness, behavior, leave

I have this stupid situation to which I don't know how to act accordingly. Last week i was on sick leave for 3 days and I forgot to bring in my sick note from doctor. Today i got paid my monthly salary which should have been smaller than usual because of the work days i skipped because I was ill. I have not talked about this with my employer and i actually don't know how to approach him with this situation.

Is this some kind of violation? What could be penalties because of this, could I got in some kind of problems? Have anyone been in this situation before, what could happen if I act like nothing is wrong and as if I was never sick? How should i approach my employer about this?

Comment: can you feign ignorance? I wouldn't mention it and if someone brings it up act surprised and say how can we remedy this situation?

Comment: do you get any paid sick leave? and do you still have the doctor's note?

Comment: i get paid, and yes i have the sick not, altho the pay is like 50% reduced in thous days.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Not the end of the world. Point out the issue to your boss and the firm's accountant, any correction they feel necessary should be reflected in your next paycheck or in whatever paychecks come after that paycheck.

Again, be comfortable pointing out the issue and be comfortable letting them deal with it. Nobody is trying to mislead anyone and anything that happened was inadvertent and in good faith. And that's the way you should approach the issue when discussing it with them. Because that's the way it happened: in inadvertance and in good faith. And of course, pointing out ASAP strengthens your credibility.

And if they choose to pay you anyway after you told them, DON'T make a fight out of it ! :)

Comment: *and ... I hate the stupid edit limit.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is probably a violation of company policies for most companies: you didn't report your sickness in a timely manner. However, you're not the first and you won't be the last person to do this and I in any place I've ever worked it wouldn't have much in the way of serious consequences so long as it's the first time something like this has happened.

Fixing it is easy: you walk into either your manager or your HR representative's office (pick which is more appropriate) and say "Hi. I screwed up. What do I need to do to make it right?". Best (and most likely in any company I've ever worked in) case scenario is they say "we'll sort it out in next month's payroll run". They could potentially ask for you to pay the money back quicker than that, in which case you say "Sure. How much?" and write them a cheque on the spot.

The last thing I'd do is to try and pretend it didn't happen. Unless you've deliberately changed the facts, you've probably posted enough information here that your employer could work out this was you if they ever see this post, and at that point it changes from being an accident to deliberately misleading your employer, and that is the sort of thing which can mean you're out of a job in a hurry.

Comment: okey I understand that is bad, I am asking this because i sorta worked in thous days while i was sick from home, thought not as mush as usual. That is why i considering to just sit quite and let it pass, even if manager find out i have leverage that i worked in thous days, and my commits can be found in git.

Comment: If you were to some extent working from home (WFH) rather than just off sick, that's a question of your contract and company policies. If there's no WFH provision in your contract, be prepared to pay the money back and just remember next time to a) get agreement for what you're doing or b) put your feet up when you're sick. If you do have a WFH provision, then you still made an error for the hours you didn't work, and that's the basis on which to open the discussion.